# c- passing argument 1 of 'strcpy' from incompatible pointer tyle

Tags: c, shell, strcpy

I am trying to write a shell program and I have an inputBuffer array that holds the command that was entered. I also have a historyBuffer array that will hold the past 10 commands that were entered. I have the global variable: `char historyBuffer[10][MAX_LINE];` (where MAX_LINE == 80) and inside the main I have `char inputBuffer[MAX_LINE];` Here is the whole main function:

```
int main(void){
    int flag;                  //equals 1 if a command is followed by '&'
    char *args[MAX_LINE/2+1];  //command line (of 80) must have <40 arguments
    int child,             //process id of the child process
    status;        //result from execvp system call
    char inputBuffer[MAX_LINE];//buffer to hold the command entered
    strcpy(historyBuffer, inputBuffer);

    signal(SIGINT, shellHandler); //called when ^C is pressed

    while(1){   //program terminates normally inside setup
        flag = 0;
        printf(" COMMAND->\n");
        setup(inputBuffer,args,&flag); //get next comman
        child = fork();   //creates a duplicate process
        switch(child){
            case -1:
                perror("Could not fork the process");
            break;  /* perror is a library routine that displays a system
                       error message, according to the value of the system
                       vaiable "errno" which will be set during a function
                       (like fork) that was unable to successfully 
                       complete its task */
            case 0: //here is the child process
                status = execvp(args[0], args);
                if(status !=0){
                    perror("Error in execvp");
                    exit(-2); //terminate this process with error code -2
                }
                break;
            default:
                if(flag==0) //handle parent, wait for child
                    while(child != wait((int *) 0));
        }//end switch
    }//end while
}//end main
```

The error is with the line `strcpy(historyBuffer, inputBuffer);`

I get the error message: `expected 'char * __restirct__' but argument is of type 'char(*)[80]'`

I'm not sure if it's an issue with the parameters in the strcpy function, if it's an issue with where I'm calling strcpy, or if it's an issue with the way I declared inputBuffer or historyBuffer? Or if it's a completely different issue that I'm oblivious to?

Comment: What are you trying to achive with this statement strcpy(historyBuffer, inputBuffer);? historyBuffer is a two-dimensional array. Moreover inputBuffer is not initialized. The code does not make sense.

Comment: `strcpy(historyBuffer, inputBuffer);` --> `strcpy(historyBuffer[n], inputBuffer);` where `n` is a number in range 0..9

Comment: Better would be `strcpy(historyBuffer, inputBuffer);` --> `strncpy(historyBuffer[n], inputBuffer, MAX_LINE);` where n is a number in range 0..9

Answer (score 0):

The two arguments to [`strcpy`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcpy.3.html) should be pointers to `char` (i.e. "strings"). But `historyBuffer` is an array of pointers to `char` (i.e. a pointer to strings).

You would need to dereference `historyBuffer` when you pass it as an argument e.g. `historyBuffer[0]`. Also since your arrays are a fixed, known size, you should really be using `strncpy` which is less prone to overflows.

That will fix the error, but your code still doesn't make any sense. `strcpy` just performs a one time copy of memory, and you are calling it at the beginning of your code when `inputBuffer` has not been initialized with anything. So it is pointless.

If you actually want to store each `inputBuffer` in `historyBuffer`, you will need to call `strcpy` after each time it is read, and have some indices set up to indicate which elements of `historyBuffer` contain valid data and which history entry should be overwritten next.